# Button hardware for RPI

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+

I have the following circuit:
[image]

I am wondering if this configuration will work if I'm trying to add buttons.

I wanted to set them up as GPIO=GPIO.PUD_DOWN and to have it activate on the rising edge, but I'm open to any change.

Comment: Links as answers are discouraged in Stack Exchange sites, hence this comment.  The GPIOZERO library has all the code needed for handling buttons.  Just use the button to ground a GPIO pin.  https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#button

Comment: none of the switches in the schematic are operational

Comment: @jsotola how so?

Comment: the switches do not connect two parts of the circuit when pressed

Comment: @jsotola when the button is pressed,  1 connects to 3. 1 and 2 are always connected and so is 3 and 4

Comment: 1 never connects to 3 .... 1 connects to 2 only when button is pressed ... 3 connects to 4 only when button is pressed

Comment: Hmm.. I'll change the circuit then and see if it works. Thank you

Comment: turn the switches 90 degrees so that R15 is shorted to ground when the button is pressed .....  you can use a piece of wire to check if it works without doing anything to the switches

Comment: I'll try that and get back here when I get the chance. Thanks again